# Embed 2 Videos Side By Side on Github Readme

Tags: github, readme

How would I embed 2 videos side by side on a github readme so that in this example MixtureVariants and the Earth Heightmap node videos would be half their current width and placed next to each other.

[image: Videos]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed MP4 files side-by-side in Markdown. The workaround is as follows.

1. Convert your MP4 files to GIF.

   - https://express.adobe.com/tools/convert-to-gif
2. Place the GIF files in Markdown as follows.

   ```markdown
   A|B
   --|--
   ![](https://example.com/a.gif)|![](https://example.com/b.gif)
   ```

   You can adjust the width of the videos if you want.

   ```markdown
   A|B
   --|--
   <img src="https://example.com/a.gif" width="600" />|<img src="https://example.com/b.gif" width="600" />
   ```

#### Example

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |